# How to pass two parameter values to couchdb views?

Tags: sql, couchdb, language-comparisons

I want to reproduce this SQL in CouchDB views.

```
SELECT name,department FROM Persons where id = ? and group_id = ? ;
```

How do I write a view and query view in CouchDB for this SQL?

Comment: I wrote the Cookbook chapter to answer questions like these: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/cookbook.html Hope this helps :)

Comment: @George this is common problem, the question is now reworded nicely, maybe you could consider reopening it

Comment: @SHernandez The accepted answer needs some help; it doesn't even have any information in it besides a link. If I was doing what is expected, I'd go ahead and convert that answer to a comment; or delete it.

Answer (score 20):

You could write a view like this one:

```
function(doc) { 
  if (doc.person_id && doc.group_id) { 
    emit([doc.person_id, doc.group_id], {"name":doc.name,"department":doc.department});
  }
}
```

I changed your id to person_id so it cannot be easily confused with _id

I used an array as key for the view, so you can easily query it like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/testdb/_design/designdoc/_view/testview?key=[12,3]
```

This would be more or less like this query:

```
SELECT name, department FROM Persons where person_id = 12 and group_id = 3 ;
```

Here is an article about filtering and ordering with views: http://barkingiguana.com/2009/01/22/filtering-and-ordering-couchdb-view-results/

There is a very good page in the couchdb wiki on views: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

This chapter in the couchdb guide explains array keys: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html

Comment: @JanLehnardt Your other comments somehow got lost. Maybe you or someone else wants to improve this a bit, just hit edit

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Been looking for this for ages. +1